# Netbeans won't start after setting jdkhome in config

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm on mac os big sur. I fully reinstalled java jdk and netbeans. It started at first, but when i tried to install my plugins I got an error message saying "the jdk is missing and is required to run some netbeans modules"
After this I set the netbeans_jdkhome to my jdk location. Now my netbeans won't even open (Newest version)

```
javac -version Output: javac 1.8.0_275


echo $JAVA_HOME Output: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home


netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: I have the same issue when change the netbeans_jdkhome in netbeans.conf to switch de default java platform for my new projects. But I'm not sure if that is the way to achieve it or if this change only affects to the platform to run the IDE on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for:
`netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"`
in
`/netbeans_install_dir/etc/netbeans.conf`

```
# Default location of JDK:
# (set by installer or commented out if launcher should decide)
#
# It can be overridden on command line by using --jdkhome <dir>
# Be careful when changing jdkhome.
# There are two NetBeans launchers for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and
# installer points to one of those in the NetBeans application shortcut 
# based on the Java version selected at installation time.
#
# netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk" `
```